# How to compare Student Object

Tags: java

How to compare Student Object

**my code**

How to compare Student Object
How to compare Student Object
How to compare Student Object
How to compare Student Object

```
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Comparator;

public class Student implements Comparable < Student >{

    private String studentName;
    private String studentDOJ;

    public String getStudentName() {
        return studentName;
    }
    public void setStudentName(String studentName) {
        this.studentName = studentName;
    }
    public String getStudentDOJ() {
        return studentDOJ;
    }
    public void setStudentDOJ(String studentDOJ) {
        this.studentDOJ = studentDOJ;
    }


  @Override
        public int compareTo(Student other) {
             DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy");
             return Comparator.comparing(LocalDate.parse(Student::getStudentDOJ,formatter)).reversed()
                     .compare(this, other);
        }

}
```

Comment: Is there any reason for the `studentDOJ` property to be of type `String` ? Why not make it a `LocalDate` ? It would avoid having to parse the string in the compareTo method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use a method reference there.

`LocalDate.parse(CharSequence, DateTimeFormatter)` doesn't take a `Function<Student, String>`, so you can't pass `Student::getStudentDOJ`.

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Student other) {
  DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy");
  return Comparator.comparing((Student student) -> LocalDate.parse(student.getStudentDOJ(), formatter)).reversed()
      .compare(this, other);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite your method like this way:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Student other) {
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy");
    return LocalDate.parse(getStudentDOJ(),formatter)
            .compareTo(LocalDate.parse(other.getStudentDOJ(),formatter));
}
```

And can sort student list of type `List<Student>` as:

```
lists.sort(Comparator.reverseOrder()); // dsc
lists.sort(Comparator.naturalOrder()); // asc
```